# ¿Evento click() y slideToggle() no me están funcionando?

Tags: jquery

Hola buenas tardes tengo un pequeño código jquery que le estoy aplicando a un menu desplegable responsive pero no me sale nada:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contador=1;

 $('i').click(function(){
  if (contador==1) {
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '0'
   });
   contador = 0;
  } else {
   contador = 1;
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '-100%'
   });
  }
 });
 
 // Mostramos y ocultamos submenus
 $('.submenu').click(function(){
  $(this).children('.hijos').slideToggle();
 });
    
});
```

```css
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,*::before,*::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

body{
    background-color: #FEFEFE;
}

div.menu-bar{
    display: none;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
}

header nav{
    background-color: #023859;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}


header nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

header nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}

header nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #E6344A;
}

header nav ul li .hijos{
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #023859;
}

header nav ul li:hover .hijos{
    display: block;
    
}

header nav ul .hijos li{
    display: block;
}

header nav ul .hijos li a{
    display: block;
}

header nav ul li i{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.caret{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    
    body{
        padding-top: 80px;
    }
    
    div.menu-bar{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        background: #E6344A;
        
    }
    
    div.menu-bar .btn-menu{
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
        color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    div.menu-bar i{
        float: right;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    header nav{
        width: 80%;
        height: calc(100%-80px);
        position: fixed;
        left: -100%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    
    header nav ul li{
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    }
    
    header nav ul li a{
        display: block;
    }
    
    header nav ul li:hover .hijos{
        display: none;
    }
    
    header nav ul li .hijos{
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    header nav ul li .hijos li a{
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .caret{
        float: right;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
   
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
      <div class="menu-bar">
          <a href="" class="btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>Menu</a>
      </div>
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Inicio</a></li>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i>Trabajos</a></li>
              <li class="submenu">
               <a href=""><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>Proyectos <i class="fas fa-angle-down caret"></i></a>
               <ul class="hijos">
                   <li><a href="#">Submenu #1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Submenu #2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Submenu #3</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-globe-americas"></i>Servicios</a></li>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>Contactos</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola. Te recomiendo que añadas el código completo en un snippet para verlo mejor.

Comment: Jesús, usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78).

Comment: mauricio como hago eso?

Comment: @JesúsCharrisVilla para hacerlo debes [editar](/edit) la pregunta y en el cuadro de edición vas a ver que tienes botones en la parte superior. El séptimo botón es para hacerlo.

Comment: Hola ya lo edité a ver si me pueden ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Mirá, había 2 problemas. Primero te estaba faltando agregar `event.preventDefault();` para evitar que el navegador refresque la pantalla. Puedes aprender a usarlo leyendo la [documentacion](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). Una vez resuelto lo primero se presentó un segundo error. Al estar seleccionando tu btn por el tipo de etiqueta $('i') al intentar acceder a los sub-menus, se disparaba el mismo evento y te lo cerraba. En otras palabras "pensaba que estabas haciendo click en el botón del menú". Esto lo solucione seleccionando el botón por su clase, ya que en este caso era única. Pero lo ideal seria hacerlo por ID. Cualquier duda me avisas. Saludos!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contador=1;

 $('.btn-menu').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if (contador==1) {
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '0'
   });
   contador = 0;
  } else {
   
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '-100%'
   });
      contador = 1;
  }
 });
 
 // Mostramos y ocultamos submenus
 $('.submenu').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
  $(this).children('.hijos').slideToggle();
 });
    
});
```

```css
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,*::before,*::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

body{
    background-color: #FEFEFE;
}

div.menu-bar{
    display: none;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
}

header nav{
    background-color: #023859;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}


header nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

header nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}

header nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #E6344A;
}

header nav ul li .hijos{
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #023859;
}

header nav ul li:hover .hijos{
    display: block;
    
}

header nav ul .hijos li{
    display: block;
}

header nav ul .hijos li a{
    display: block;
}

header nav ul li i{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.caret{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    
    body{
        padding-top: 80px;
    }
    
    div.menu-bar{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        background: #E6344A;
        
    }
    
    div.menu-bar .btn-menu{
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
        color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    div.menu-bar i{
        float: right;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    header nav{
        width: 80%;
        height: calc(100%-80px);
        position: fixed;
        left: -100%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    
    header nav ul li{
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    }
    
    header nav ul li a{
        display: block;
    }
    
    header nav ul li:hover .hijos{
        display: none;
    }
    
    header nav ul li .hijos{
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    header nav ul li .hijos li a{
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .caret{
        float: right;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
   
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
      <div class="menu-bar">
          <a href="#" class="btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>Menu</a>
      </div>
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Inicio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i>Trabajos</a></li>
              <li class="submenu">
               <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>Proyectos <i class="fas fa-angle-down caret"></i></a>
               <ul class="hijos">
                   <li><a href="#">Submenu #1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Submenu #2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Submenu #3</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-globe-americas"></i>Servicios</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>Contactos</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: Hola Fran muchas gracias era eso.

Comment: @JesúsCharrisVilla De nada, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

a ver si alguno me puede ayudar, tengo exactamente el mismo codigo (Falconmasters) y tambien lo estoy utilizando en un menu. Mis habilidades con java son nulas, solo "copy/paste".
Aplicando la solucion de @Fran-Islas consegui que al menos al cerrar el menu no se reinicie la pagina, pero me sucede que al dar click en el sub menu si sigue sucediendo.
Me gustaria poder hacer o siguiente:
Una vez abierto el menu desde el boton, que este se cierre dando click en cualquier lugar de la pagina, que al dar click en un link del menu este se cierre y vaya al link.

Intentare copiar el codigo aqui debajo, primera vez que utilizo esto, muchas gracias!

```js
$(document).ready(main);

var contador = 1;

function main () {
 $('.icon-menu').click(function(){

  if (contador == 1) {
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '0'
   });
   contador = 0;
  } else {
   contador = 1;
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '-100%'
   });
  }
 });

 $('.submenu').click(function(){
  $(this).children('.children').slideToggle();
 });
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.fondo-modal {
 background: #333;
}

button:focus {
 outline: none;
}

.menu_bar {
 display: none;
}

header {
 width: 100%;
}

.menu_bar span {
 color: #3c69a0;
}

header nav {
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 10px 50px;
 z-index: 1000;
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #3c69a0;
 position: fixed;
}

header nav span {
 color: #3c69a0;
}

header .logo {
 width: 170px;
}

header nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 float: right;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
header nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

header nav ul li .children {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 width: 150%;
 z-index: 1000;
}

header nav ul li:hover .children {
 display: block;
 background: #fff;
}

header nav ul li .children li {
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

header nav ul li .children li a {
 display: block;
 background: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
}

header nav ul li .children li:hover {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

header nav ul li a {
 color: #3c69a0;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 font-size: 26px;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
 font-weight: bolder;
}

header nav ul li a span {
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.portada, .portada-gracias {
 background-image: url(../img/pmadero.jpg);
 background-position: center top;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.portada-gracias {
 background-image: url(../img/silueta-ba.jpg);
}

.portada-gracias span {
 font-size: 4vw;
 color: #3c699f;
}

.contenedor-reserva {
 margin-top: 25%;
 text-align: center;
}

.portada a span{
 font-size: 5vw;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #fff;
}

.titulo-reserva {
 text-align: center;
 background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.5), rgba(0,0,0,0));
 padding: 20px;
}

.titulo-reserva h1 {
 font-size: 10vh;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #fff;
}

.reserva {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 border-radius: 5px;
 display: none;
}

.reserva form {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
}

.reserva input, .reserva select, .reserva button {
 width: 50%;
 margin: 15px 5px 15px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-style: italic;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

select {
 color: #999;
}

.reserva button {
 width: 10%;
 margin-right: 15px;
 color: #fff;
 background: #3c69a0;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.reserva {
 padding-left: 15px;
}

#deptos, #contacto {
 margin-top: -50px;
 position: absolute;
}

.deptos {
 padding: 40px 0px 0px;
 background-image: url(../img/silueta-ba.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: bottom;
 background-size: cover;
 text-align: center;
}

.depto {
 width: 70%;
 margin: 0px auto 20px;
 padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 text-align: justify;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.depto img {
 float: left;
}

.depto .descripcion {
 height: 280px;
 color: #666;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 padding: 0px 20px;
}

.depto .descripcion .titulo {
 font-style: oblique;
}

.container-deptos {
 text-align: center;
}

.deptos h1, .contacto h1 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 10vh;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #ccc;
 letter-spacing: 8px;
}

.deptos .icon-key {
 font-size: 4vh;
 color: #666;
 margin-right: 40px;
 border: 3px solid #666;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

/* ------------------ slide deptos ------------------ */

.slider-container {
 width:65%;
 margin:auto;
 position:relative;
}

.slider-container2 {
 margin:auto;
 position:relative;
}

.slider {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 animation:opac 01s;
}

@keyframes opac {
 from {
  opacity:0
 } 
 to {
  opacity:1
 }
}

.slide {
 margin: 3px;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: left;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: -3px 3px 10px #ccc;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.slide:hover {
 box-shadow: -6px 6px 10px #aaa;
}

.slide h3, span{
 color: #666;
 font-weight: lighter;
}

.slide button {
 width: 100%;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-color: #a9a9a9;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: #666;
}

.slide img {
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.arrow-left, .arrow-right {
 margin: 0 20px;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #bbb;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
}

.arrow-left:hover, .arrow-right:hover {
 color: #aaa;
}

.slider-container2 a {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 24px;
}

/* ------------------ end slide deptos ------------------ */

.iframe-map {
 margin: 0px auto;
 width: 100%;
}

/* ------------------ modal ------------------ */

.modal {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
}

.modal .slider-container {
 width: 50%;
 margin: 50px auto;
}

.modal img {
 width: 100%;
}

.modal .description {
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #fff;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 100%;
}

.modal .arrow-left, .modal .arrow-right {
 font-size: 40px;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
 background-color: transparent;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 20% 20px;
 top: 35%;
 position: absolute;
 border: none;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0%,-50%);
 -moz-transform: translate(0%,-50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(0%,-50%);
 -o-transfor: translate(0%,-50%);
 transform: translate(0%,-50%);
}

.modal .arrow-right {
 right: 0;
}

.modal .arrow-left:hover, .modal .arrow-right:hover {
 background-color: transparent;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}

.modal span {
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #000;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* ------------------ end modal ------------------ */

iframe {
 border: none;
}

.contacto {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 60px;
 background-image: url(../img/contactbg.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.contacto .icon-pencil {
 font-size: 4vh;
 color: #666;
 margin-right: 40px;
 border: 3px solid #666;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.container-contact {
 text-align: center;
 width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-contact input, textarea {
 width: 45%;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 0px 10px 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 border-radius: 10px;
 font-size: 100%;
}

.container-contact textarea {
 width: 92.5%;
 height: 80px;
}

.container-contact button {
 width: 30%; 
 height: 40px;
 margin-top: 40px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 background: #3c69a0;    
 border: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #777;
 font-style: italic;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
 color: #777;
 font-style: italic;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
 color: #777;
 font-style: italic;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: #777;
 font-style: italic;
}

/* ------------------ datepicker ------------------ */

.ui-datepicker {
    width: 290px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 9px #ddd;
}

table.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    width: 100%;
}

td {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 4px 0px;
}

.ui-datepicker-header {
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}

th {
 padding: 10px 0px;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev {
 float: left;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-datepicker-next {
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
}

a:visited.ui-state-default {
 color: blue;
}

/* ------------------ end datepicker ------------------ */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}

footer {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}

.footer-gracias {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

.redes-contacto a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}

.redes {
 font-size: 28px;
}

.redes-contacto {
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 20px 100px;
 background: #3c69a0;
 font-size: 28px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.redes-contacto span {
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #fff;
}

.redes {
 font-size: 28px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 width: 30%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
 
 .contenedor-reserva {
  width: 60%;
 }

 .slider-container {
  width: 85%;
 }

 .redes {
  width: 50%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 
 .menu_bar {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3c69a0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
 }

 .bt-menu {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #3c69a0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
 }

 .menu_bar span {
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
 }

 .logo {
  display: none;
 }

 .icono-menu {
  width: 180px;
 }

 header nav {
  width: 40%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 73px;
  right: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
 }

 header nav ul {
  float: left;
  width: 100%
 }

 header nav ul li {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
 }

 header nav ul li a {
  display: block;
 }

 header nav ul li .children {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
 }

 header nav ul li:hover .children {
  display: none;
 }

 header nav ul li .children li a {
  margin-left: 20px;
 }

 header nav ul li .caret {
  float:  right;
 }

 .portada-gracias span {
  font-size: 8vw;
 }

 .contenedor-reserva {
  width: 90%;
 }

 .titulo-reserva h1 {
  font-size: 8vw;
 }

 .slider {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 80px auto 40px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
 }

 .slide {
  margin: 8px;
 }

 .depto {
  width: 90%;
 }

 .modal .slider-container {
  width: 80%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 
 .portada {
  height: 100vh;
 }

 .contenedor-reserva {
  width: 100%;
 }

 .reserva {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 20px;
 }

 .reserva form {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
 }

 .reserva input, .reserva select, .reserva button {
  width: 48%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
 }

 .portada a span {
  font-size: 10vw;
 }

 .deptos {
  padding: 20px 0px;
 }

 .slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  justify-content: center;
 }

 .container-contact {
  width: 100%;
 }

 .contacto {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 30px 90px;
 }

 .redes {
  width: 100%;
 }

 .modal .arrow-left, .modal .arrow-right {
  top: 30%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {

 .container-contact input, textarea {
  width: 80%;
 }

 .container-contact textarea {
  width: 80%;
 }

 .slider-container {
  margin-top:  0px;
 }

 .depto {  
  padding: 20px;
 }

 .depto img {
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

 .depto .descripcion {
  padding: 0px;
 }

 .modal .slider-container {
     width: 95%;
 }

 .modal .arrow-left, .modal .arrow-right {
  top: 25%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 
 .portada {
  height: 110vh;
 }

 .titulo-reserva h1 {
  font-size: 8vw;
 }

 .reserva {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
 }

 .reserva input, .reserva select, .reserva button {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .deptos h1, .contacto h1 {
  font-size: 6vw;
 }

 .contacto {
  padding: 30px 0;
 }

 .redes-contacto {
  padding: 20px 10px;
 }

 .modal .arrow-left, .modal .arrow-right {
  padding: 25% 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 20%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {

 .titulo-reserva h1 {
  font-size: 14vw;
 }

 .deptos h1, .contacto h1 {
  font-size: 5vh;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
 }

 .redes-contacto span {
  font-size: 35px;
 }

 .container-contact button {
  margin-top: 0px;
 }

 .modal .arrow-left, .modal .arrow-right {
  top: 15%;
 }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="menu_bar">
   <a href="#"><img class="icono-menu" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="BArent Alquileres Temporarios"></a>
   <a href="#" class="bt-menu">
    <span class="icon-menu"></span>    
   </a>
  </div>
  <nav>
   <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="BArent Alquileres Temporarios"></a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#deptos"><span class="icon-key"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#map"><span class="icon-map"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacto"><span class="icon-mail"></span></a></li>
    <li>
     <a href=""><span class="icon-chat"></span><span class="caret icon-chevron-small-down"></span></a>
     <ul class="children">
      <li><a href="/english/index.html">INGLES</a></li>
      <li><a href="/portugues/index.html">PORTUGUES</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Puedes crear tu propia pregunta y poner esta pregunta de referencia como indica [Referir preguntas propias asociadas a otra pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3494/referir-preguntas-propias-asociadas-a-otra-pregunta). Saludos.

Comment: perfecto, gracias!